# Puzzle for those who do not know ASL

Tags: visual

A puzzle for those who do not know [ASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language). The answer is a phrase.

[image]

Source: https://youtu.be/gFIRSrbHrB4

Comment: I hope the answer is not net catch.

Comment: No, but it seems to be half of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title implies it is to be solved by people with *no knowledge of ASL*; however, by definition this group of people will *not* be able to solve it! Meanwhile, to those who *do* know ASL, it is not a puzzle at all, merely a translation. In its current state it will invite lots of speculative answers.

Comment: I think this type of thing *could* potentially work as a puzzle, but it would have to be very inferable for people who don't know any ASL. (Perhaps providing translation samples and then a message to be translated, like the [International Linguistics Olympiad](https://ioling.org/problems/samples/) questions.) But as-is, this doesn't seem gettable at all.

Answer (score 1):

The video literally says

> "Net throw help catch".
>  In context, it could say "help catch it by throwing a net".

This isn't really a puzzle so much as it is an exercise in ASL interpreting.